# SQL Server Connection String fails when underscores are present

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssms

I am using C# and Blazor Server, and when I try to connect to a database named according to the syntax 'A_B_C', it tells me that the user cannot connect to 'A_B'.

As far as I understand, one underscore works but the second and the following characters goes away.

Ideas how to get around this?

The connection string looks like this:

string cs = "Data Source=DS; Initial Catalog=A_B_C; User ID='User'; Password=Pass;";

Comment: You can try to use a .udl file for connection. After that just copy a composed connection from the .udl file.

Comment: Post your actual connection string, actual code and *actual full exception text* - not just the exception type or message. Why do you assume the problem are the underscores? Have you tried connecting to the database using SSMS?

Comment: Which ADO.NET Client are you using? The older System.Data.SqlClient or its replacement, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient?

Comment: Are you sure the second underscore is actually an underscore, maybe it's a Low Macron character `ˍ` Please copy and paste your connection string into your post *exactly* without pasting it anywhere else first.

Comment: If you have access to the target SQL Server instance using SSMS... have you looked in the SQL Server Logs for any Error 18456 login failure messages? Take note of any `State` numbers shown there and compare them against [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine the cause of the login failure. Potentially the requested database doesn't exist, or the SQL Login just doesn't have the required access to it.